# How can I do a select where such as this query in hibernate without using a query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, nosql, hql

I have the below function in my hibernate file:

```
try {
  SessionFactory sessFact = new Configuration()
  .configure("/org/test/tutorial/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
  Session sess = sessFact.openSession();
  Transaction tran = sess.beginTransaction();
  List<testModel> hostsInHostclass = sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM Employee where Employer like '"+ANY INPUT+"'").addEntity(tut_model.class).list(); 

    } catch (HibernateException he) {
        throw new DependencyException("DB Error: " + he.getMessage());
    }
```

Now, writing it this was defeats the purpose of hibernate since I have to actually specify the query. Is there any way I can do this implicitly?

Assume that my model file is correct. It has four columns: Employee, Employer, Age and Sex. Please do help me out with this.

Comment: Four Columns. Sorry. That's in the database, which the model specifies correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
sess.createQuery("from Employee e where e.employer = :emp").
        setEntity("emp", anEmployerInstance).list();
```

where `Employee` is the name of your entity, `employer` is the name of the property in `Employee` class that match the `Employer` DB field, `emp` is an arbitrary name and `anEmployerInstance` is an instance of `Employer` class.

I supposed in this answer that `Employer` is another entity, so I used `setEntity()` method. But I can't be sure as I have no access to the `Employee` entity code.

Comment: What if I wish to give it an input? Say String x?

So is the query now" 

sess.createQuery("from Employee e where e.employer = :"+a).
        setEntity(a, anEmployerInstance).list();

Comment: The query I wrote is a parameterized query. At running time, `emp` is replaced by the instance you pass in the `setEntity()` method. You can't replace an instance by a String.

Comment: Oh. Is there a way to do this with a String?

Comment: If the property `employer` in the `Employee` class is a `String`, then replace `setEntity(String, Entity)` with `setString(String, String)`. The first parameter is the name of the parameter in the query (`emp`) and the second one is the value of the `employer` property you are looking for.